# Nested for loop to output your name 500 times

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

need to create a code using nested for loops to output a name 500 times, i'm stuck on this part help please

Comment: Programming language?

Comment: How many nested levels?

Comment: Missing the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i<250; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<2; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Your Name");
    }
}
```

Comment: This loops 500 times or  250 times?

Comment: Please think before ask something like "This loops 500 times or 250 times?". Programing is not snacks available.